# How to download a page with "Transfer-Encoding:chunked" prior to PHP 5.2

Tags: php, filter, stream, chunked

Trying to retrieve a page from the XML language. However, retrieval is unreliable because it is a chunked transfer encoding. How do I download this page correctly to give me further editing?

I can not use PHP Stream Filters because my PHP version is only 5.2.

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the file?

Comment: "retrieve a page from the xml language"?

Comment: @zneak i will post new coment. 

function readfile_chunked ($filename,$type='array'){
$chunk_array=array();
$chunksize = 1*(1024*1024);
$buffer = '';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'rb');
if ($handle === false) {
return false;
}
while (!feof($handle)) {
switch($type)
{
case'array':
$lines[] = fgets($handle, $chunksize);
break;
case'string':
$lines = fread($handle, $chunksize);
break;
}
}
fclose($handle);
return $lines;
} 
foreach ( readfile_chunked('http://api.justin.tv/stream/list.xml?language=en&stream_type=live') as $key=>$value) {$res .= $value;
}
file_put_contents('file.xml', $res);

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal yes it is xml file with television.

Comment: @trymerson2010: "xml file with television"?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php). It supports HTTP/1.1, which is neccessary to reliably receive chunked data. The PHP core functions like `file_get_contents` and the like <strike>do not support HTTP/1.1</strike> [do not support chunked data before PHP 5.3.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php).

**EDIT**

Rephrased to clarify. Thank you, @troelskn.

**EDIT**

Example using cURL:

```
$rCURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/file_to_retrieve.xml');
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($rCURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$aData = curl_exec($rCURL);

curl_close($rCURL);

var_dump($aData);
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that http/1.1 isn't supported before `5.3`?

Comment: @troelskn: argl, I should've been more clear about that. I don't mean that HTTP/1.1 isn't supported before 5.3.0, but [chunked data isn't](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) (see Changelog).

Comment: You might be on to something. The stream wrappers `protocol_version` (or context setting) might be misconfigured. Or OPs server is not fully compliant and replies with /1.1 even if the php user agent requested with /1.0 (and chunked is indeed a requirement for 1.1, not 1.0)

Comment: any idea how to get this file using cURL or  any other method?

Comment: Yes, but it still breaking the content. 

Look at source of http://www.waszapolska.tv/justintv/justin.php 
This is a source of php file http://www.waszapolska.tv/justintv/justin.html

Comment: @trymerson2010: Looking at the first link I'd say the download is completely ok and works properly. The problem is most likely that you are downloading an HTML (not an XML) file, which has set `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` but uses UTF-8 characters inside (first one found at line 2, pos 120). But this could also be my editor getting it wrong. Anyhow, the download is ok. Beyond this I'm out^^

Comment: what if it stops in the middle of it? how do you determine the error then?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension.

Or for simple GET requests, just use the built-in wrappers (E.g. `file_get_contents`)

Answer (score 0):

Use [ext/curl](http://php.net/curl) to download the file.

Comment: How is proper comand to use curl? Becouse even wget is breaking down downloading file.

Comment: I do not recommend to use curl command line but the php extension; that's why I added a link to the appropriate manual section